# 1 id for more items

Tags: php, mysql, oracle11g

I have a form request_form.php, that is manage Purchase Request Form for request item.

Purchase_Request_No : (automatic - autoincrement)
Date :
Dept : 
Supplier : 
Item_Request : 
Example have a 5 row :

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.

I want to make once Purchase Request have 1 Purchase_Request_No.
Example :
Purchase_Request_No : 17
Date :25-Jul-2012
Dept :Production
Supplier :Microsoft
Item_Request : 
1.Windows XP Professional
2.Keyboard
3.Mouse
4.LCD Monitor
5.Speaker

So, how can I make it with 1 Purchase_Request_No with item request more than 1 item(in this case I put 5 items)?

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks for advance.

---

Hi all, back again now I already in coding the concept.
It's successfully save the data into database, but still when insert 5 item, it submit the data per item per ID.
Example :
Item 1 - Computer (Purchase No 1)
Item 2 - Mouse (Purchase No 2)

That I wanted is :
Item 1 - Computer (Purchase No 1)
Item 2 - Mouse (Purchase No 1)

and here it's my code :
I using purchase no with autoincrement.

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("system", "dev01");
$n = $_POST['jum'];
for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
$dept=$_POST['dept'];
$date_request=$_POST['date_request'];
$supplier=$_POST['supplier'];   

$item=$_POST['item'.$i];    
$qty=$_POST['qty'.$i];  
$uprice=$_POST['uprice'.$i];    
$total=$_POST['total'.$i];  

$s = oci_parse($conn,
"insert into purchase_request(dept_id, supplier_id, date_request, item, qty, uprice, total_amount) values ('$dept', '$supplier', '$date_request', '$item'
, '$qty', '$uprice', '$total'
)");

$r = oci_execute($s);

oci_rollback($conn);

echo "Data was committed\n";
}
?>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: 2 tables, a purchase table and an item table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have three tables.  One would contain the products:

```
id    Product
1     Windows XP Professional
2     Keyboard
3     Mouse
4     LCD Monitor
5     Speaker
```

another contains the requests:

```
id    request_date    dept       supplier
1     25-Jul-2012     Production Microsoft
```

The third maps the first two together

```
id  request_id  item_id
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   1           4
5   1           5
```

(Alternately, you could make the ids of the products prime numbers and store the `items` column as a multiple of the items.  All you'd need to do is find the prime factors of the `items` column, and then you've got the list of items!*)

*For some reason, no one at work thinks this is a good idea.

Comment: items - bad: Non-first normal form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: People probably disagree with this idea because you're storing coma separated values for the request items, which is usually very bad practice.  They should be stored as individual lines in a table of their own with a foreign key to the request id.

Comment: hi... How about if I don't want to save master data for items ?

Comment: What do you mean "master data"?

Comment: You explain that product must be set in table before, right ? So what about if product not in list in table ?

Comment: You can insert the product into the products table before creating the entry in the requests/map tables.

Comment: If you don't want a master table of items, you can just put the item names in the last table instead of item_id.

Comment: Hi all, I updated the concept into coding. Please check in the top my post. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @ImProgrammer I'd suggest you start a new question if you have a new question, rather than editing the old one.  Also, don't forget to upvote and accept:http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @SomeKittens Much better, glad my limited DB knowledge could help :)

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is to create two table say

```
Purchase
Purchase_Id (Primary Key)
Supplier_Id: (foreign key referring Supplier table)
Purchase_date: datetime

Purchase_Items_Details
purchase_item_id (primary key)
purchase_id (foreign key to Purchase table)
item_id (foreign key to Products/Items table)
qty (Quantity)
```

Where In `Purchase` table you will Enter only Basic Purchase detail and Details about purchase will be added to the `Purchase_Items_Details`