# Insert ID for 5 items or More

Tags: php, oracle11g

I continued from the previous topic - [1 id for more items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680950/1-id-for-more-items) - that I discuss.

In that last topic, I ask about the concept and now what I'm doing is continue to coding concept.

The code successfully save the data into database, but still when insert 5 item, it submit the data per item per ID. Example :
Item 1 - Computer (Purchase No 1)
Item 2 - Mouse (Purchase No 2)
That I wanted is :
Item 1 - Computer (Purchase No 1)
Item 2 - Mouse (Purchase No 1)

and here it's my code : I using purchase no with autoincrement.

Here it's my execute code :

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("system", "dev01");
$n = $_POST['jum'];
for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
$dept=$_POST['dept'];
$date_request=$_POST['date_request'];
$supplier=$_POST['supplier']; 
$item=$_POST['item'.$i]; 
$qty=$_POST['qty'.$i];  
$uprice=$_POST['uprice'.$i]; 
$total=$_POST['total'.$i];  
$s = oci_parse($conn,
"insert into purchase_request(dept_id, supplier_id, date_request, item, qty, uprice, total_amount) values ('$dept', '$supplier', '$date_request', '$item'
, '$qty', '$uprice', '$total'

)");

$r = oci_execute($s);
oci_rollback($conn);
echo "Data was committed\n";
}
?>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to change. Can you elaborate?

Comment: hi.. I explain the topics in previous post. Please see in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680950/1-id-for-more-items

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the suggestion you marked as accepted in your earlier post, but don't make purchase ID an autoincrement field. The whole point is that it doesn't auto-increment; it goes up when you specifically want it to (so that multiple items can have the same purchase_id). This does mean you'll need to explicitly assign it a value. The simplest way would be to query for the maximum purchase id that's currently in the purchases table, and for your query, add 1 to that.